# Make Clion consider ".h" files as C++

Tags: clion

Is there a way to make CLion consider single files with ".h" extension as C++ by default and not C?

If they are not included in the CMake script, and there is no corresponding ".cc" file, it consideres them as C by default for the syntax highlighing.

Comment: can you just name them *.hpp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In current 2018.1 version it should be treated properly as C++, one limitation is: if there is no C++ files in the configuration at all, then C will be selected.